# are f# computational expressions a form of aspect oriented programming?

Tags: f#, aspect-oriented, monad

are monads, or more specifically f# computational expressions, a form of aspect oriented programming?

Update:

f# workflow builders have methods other than bind and unit. They have hooks for lots of keywords. see [Creating a New Type of Computation Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233182.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the extent that monads serve to isolate a generalized computation strategy from the specifics of its algorithm or implementation, they can be seen as a basis or theoretical foundation for AOP. I found an interesting paper called [Monads as a theoretical foundation for AOP (PDF)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.25.8262&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that gives this idea a more thorough treatment.

Comment: ugh, am I going to have to learn scheme too? I already feel like I need to learn Haskell just to learn about functional programming. LOL. /end rant

Comment: Learning new languages is fun!

Comment: After you have the first one down, yes. When you are trying to learn a new programming paradigm, one is enough. I will have to add, functional programming seems more 'natural' to me somehow. I'm starting to get frustrated with c# and what it can't do, the more I work with f#.

Comment: You only really need to grok the syntax to follow the examples.

Comment: well I guess i need to spend an afternoon learning scheme, so i can 'grok the syntax'

Answer (score 1):

for me it somewhat feels a bit like AOP.
Classic example in my work is using a "log-Workflow" (better known as a state-monad with the state beeing a log-entry) for loging inside my F#-code to spare me from passing the log-object through every method-call.
On the other hand "real" AOP doesn't need you to write log-code inside your methods at all (maybe some attributes).
I don't like the "hey I rewrite your code for you"-AOP frameworks so I just use Unity-Injection from time to time (yes I really use Unity - does everything I want from it) and it's ok.